# Should not abort ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL broadcast according to API, but nothing happens

Tags: android

The API on the [ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL) says:

> Any BroadcastReceiver receiving this Intent must not abort the broadcast

When I do (that is, abort the call) by calling `abortBroadcast()` nothing happens. No error, not even a warning or an information message. *Why* is this statement put in the API Javadoc?

```
public class OutgoingCallInterceptor extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        abortBroadcast();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly to let developers know that doing so will foul up the action (placing a phone call)?

When you about the broadcast I'm assuming that the call fails correct?

Comment: Yes, it cancels everything and doesn't call out. However, the API suggest the proper way to abort the phone call is to use setResultData with a null argument. This indeed does prevent the call from being made, but still, why the fuss about not aborting the broadcast with the abortBroadcast() message?

Comment: @Johan I'm not really sure, I'd guess you'd have to get one of the Google engineers in here to answer that

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that there are some system receivers (loggers?!) which always want to have a go at the broadcast message... In the mean time I'll try to find a Google engineer (any tips on where I can find one? ;-)